# Variable not available for a batch query string

Tags: apex, querylocator

I am working on a method that is apart of a batch class to query for Contacts. I'm trying to see if the field "CASL_Compliant_Source__c" is in a keyet that I passed to a makestring method.

I keep getting an error when I run the batch in debug:

> Variable does not exist: s

```
global class NPD_Batch_CASLCompliance implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
{
Map<String, Date> sources = new Map<String, Date>();  

public NPD_Batch_CASLCompliance() 
{         
    this.sources = sources;
    Date inquiryDate = System.today().addMonths(-6);
    Date relationshipDate = System.today().addYears(-2);
    sources.put('Contact Initiated the Inquiry', inquiryDate);
    sources.put('Business Relationship', relationshipDate);     
}

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) 
{ 
    String query = makeString(sources); 
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) 
{
    NPD_CASLCompliance.actions(sources, scope);
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) 
{
}

/*
    * MethodName        : makeString
    * param             : Map<String, Date> sources
    * Description       : This method will make a string to use as a query
*/

public String makeString(Map<String, Date> sources)
{
    Set<String> s = sources.keySet();

    String query = 
        'SELECT Id, ' +
        '       CASL_Compliant_Date__c, ' +
        '       CASL_Compliant_Source__c, ' +
        '       CASL_Compliant__c ' +
        'FROM   Contact ' +
        'WHERE  CASL_Compliant_Source__c IN :s ' + 
        'AND    CASL_Compliant__c = TRUE';
    return query; 
}
```

If I make the variable within the method why would it not exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets expand your code:

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) 
{ 
    String query = makeString(sources); 
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
```

Becomes:

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) 
    { 
        String query = makeString(sources); 
        return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id, ' +
        '       CASL_Compliant_Date__c, ' +
        '       CASL_Compliant_Source__c, ' +
        '       CASL_Compliant__c ' +
        'FROM   Contact ' +
        'WHERE  CASL_Compliant_Source__c IN :s ' + 
        'AND    CASL_Compliant__c = TRUE');
    }
```

Now after expansion, does your `s` variable exists in start method? No the `s` varible's scope was just in `makeString` method. After that it does not exists. And hence it gives you an error.

**Fix**: Make your `s` as an instance variable, so that its present in start.

```
global class NPD_Batch_CASLCompliance implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    private Set<String> s;
    public String makeString(Map<String, Date> sources){
        s = sources.keySet();

        String query = 
        'SELECT Id, ' +
        '       CASL_Compliant_Date__c, ' +
        '       CASL_Compliant_Source__c, ' +
        '       CASL_Compliant__c ' +
        'FROM   Contact ' +
        'WHERE  CASL_Compliant_Source__c IN :s ' + 
        'AND    CASL_Compliant__c = TRUE';
        return query; 
    }
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){ 
        String query = makeString(sources); 
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use Apex binding in Dynamic SOQL, the bound variables must be in scope *at the point when `Database.query()` is called*, rather than at the point when the query string is initialized.

Here, you'd probably want to create an instance variable (`sourceKeys`?), and bind to that. Doing so ensures that the bind's scope covers all of your instance methods.